# Android OnActivityResult, on second call second activity doesn't return to the first activity after finish

Tags: c#, android

Second activity is called from my First Activity

```
        public static int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
            myButton.Click += delegate
            {
                StartActivityForResult(typeof(SecondActivity), REQUEST_CODE);
            };
```

In the First Activity I override OnActivityResult

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Android.App.Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {

            if (requestCode == 1)
            {
                if (resultCode == Android.App.Result.Ok)
                {
                    String newdata = data.GetStringExtra("data");
                }
            }
        }
```

In my second activity I return to the first activity using the following code

```
       Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
       returnIntent.PutExtra("data", somedata);
       SetResult(Android.App.Result.Ok, returnIntent);
       Finish();
```

This all works well the first go round, I return to the first activity with the correct data.  However, the next time the second activity is started, the data is stored correctly, but the activity doesn't finish.  It is almost as if the Finish command is ignored and the activity is started again and OnCreate() is invoked.  Following that, the next time the above code is invoked it returns to the first activity and two key value pairs are stored in the data.  So the data is stored correctly, however the navigation is incorrect.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Use `Intent` to startActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Intent` to start an `Activity`

```
StartActivityForResult(new Intent(this, typeof(SecondActivity)), REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but when I try this using C# and visual studio 2017.  I get an error indicating 'The name intent does not exist in the current context'.  If I try UpperCase - Intent, I get an error indicating 'Non-invocable member 'Activity.Intent' can not be used like a method.'

Comment: Use `new` keyword before `Intent`

Comment: Thanks - I can execute it now, but I get the same result.